# Sum columns depending on another column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with **summing** the fields values **based on another** fields value.

I need to `SUM(activities.points)` based on `activities.activity_type` if it's `used_points` or `added_points` and put it in `AS used_points/added_points`.

Table *activities*:

```
id | subscription_id  | activity_type | points
--------------------------------------------------
1  |         1        |  used_points  |   10
2  |         1        |  used_points  |   50 
3  |         1        | added_points  |   20 
4  |         1        | added_points  |   30
5  |         2        |  used_points  |   20
6  |         2        |  used_points  |   45
7  |         2        | added_points  |   45
8  |         2        | added_points  |   45
```

Table *subscriptions*:

```
id |     name    |  current_points
-------------------------------------
 1 |    card_1   |        700
 2 |    card_2   |        900
```

What I need:

```
  name   |  current_points  | used_points | added_points
-----------------------------------------------------------
 card_1  |         700      |     60      |     50
 card_2  |         900      |     65      |     90
```

What I tried :

```
SELECT
    subscriptions.name,
    subscriptions.current_points,
    IF(activities.activity_type="used_points", SUM(activities.points), null)
        AS used_points,
    IF(activities.activity_type="added_points", SUM(activities.points), null)
        AS added_points 
FROM activities
JOIN subscriptions
    ON activities.subscription.id = subscription.id
GROUP BY subscriptions.name
```

Which is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You want to use **`SUM(IF(  ))`**. That is, remove the `SUM` aggregate function from inside the `IF` expression, and instead wrap the `IF` expression in a `SUM`. The IF expression needs to operate on individual rows, the the SUM will aggregate the value returned for each row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `SUM(IF( ))`.  You want to add up the values returned from the `IF`. You want that `IF` expression to be evaluated for each individual row. Then, use the `SUM` aggregate to add up the value returned for each row.

Remove the `SUM` aggregate from inside the `IF` expression and instead, wrap the `IF` inside a `SUM`.

---

**Followup**

**Q** But why SUM() inside of IF doesn't work ?

**A** Well, it does work. It's just not working the way you want it to work.

The MySQL `SUM` function is an "aggregate" function. It aggregates rows together, and returns a single value.

For an expression of this form:  `IF(col='foo',SUM(numcol),0)`

What MySQL is doing is aggregating all the rows into the SUM, and returning a single value.

Other databases would pitch a fit, and throw an error with the reference to the non-aggregate `col` in that expression. MySQL is more lenient, and treats the `col` reference like it was an aggregate (like MIN(col), or MAX(col)... working on a group of rows, and returning a single value. In this case, MySQL is selecting a single, sample row. (It's not determinate which row will be "chosen" as the sample row.)  So that reference to `col` is sort of like a `GET_VALUE_FROM_SAMPLE_ROW(col)`. Once the aggregates are completed, then that IF expression gets evaluated once.

If you start with this query, this is the set of rows you want to operate on.

```
SELECT s.name
     , s.current_points
     , a.activity_type
     , a.points
     , IF(a.activity_type='used_points',a.points,NULL) AS used_points
     , IF(a.activity_type='added_points',a.points,NULL) AS added_points
  FROM subscriptions s
  JOIN activities a
    ON a.subscription_id = s.id
```

When you add a GROUP BY clause, that's going to aggregate some of those rows together. What you will get back for the non-aggregates is values from a sample row.

Try adding `GROUP BY s.name` to the query, and see what is returned.

Also try adding in some aggregates, such as SUM(a.points)

```
SELECT s.name
     , s.current_points
     , a.activity_type
     , a.points
     , IF(a.activity_type='used_points',a.points,NULL) AS used_points
     , IF(a.activity_type='added_points',a.points,NULL) AS added_points
     , SUM(a.points) AS total_points
  FROM subscriptions s
  JOIN activities a
    ON a.subscription_id = s.id
 GROUP BY s.name
```

Finally, we can add in the expressions in your query into the SELECT list:

```
     , IF(a.activty_type='used_points',SUM(a.points),NULL) AS if_used_sum
     , IF(a.activty_type='added_points',SUM(a.points),NULL) AS if_added_sum
```

What we discover is that the value returned from these expressions will either be SUM(a.points), which will match the `total_points`, or it will be NULL.  And we can see the value of the `activity_type` column, retrieved from a single, sample row for each group, and we can see that this is expression is "working", it's just not doing what we you really want to happen: for the conditional test to run on each individual row, returning a value for points or a null, and then summing that up for the group.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be working. But why `SUM()` inside of `IF` doesn't work ?

Comment: The SUM is evaluated for ALL the rows aggregated together, and it returns a single value. If that's inside an IF, then the IF function gets evaluated only once, for the one value returned by the SUM function. Other databases would pitch a fit (throw an error) with your SQL statement, because the other expression in the IF is not an aggregate. MySQL is more lenient, and will choose a single, sample row from all of the rows that were included in the SUM aggregate, and use the value from the sample row as if it were an aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is only slightly out:

```
SELECT
    subscriptions.name,
    subscriptions.current_points,
    SUM(IF(activities.activity_type="used_points", 0, activities.points))
        AS used_points,
    SUM(IF(activities.activity_type="added_points", 0, activities.points))
        AS added_points 
FROM activities
JOIN subscriptions
    ON activities.subscription_id = subscription.id
GROUP BY subscriptions.name, subscriptions.current_points
```

Note the fixed typo in the second last line - you wrote subscription.id instead of subscription_id. Also you only grouped by name instead of name and current_points, not sure if that's allowed in mysql (I use T-SQL), it's good practice to have it there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did it not using the IF statement. Here's the example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/076c3f/12):

```
SELECT
    subs.name,
    subs.current_points,
    (SELECT SUM(points) FROM activities WHERE type = 1 AND subs_id = subs.id) AS used_points,
    (SELECT SUM(points) FROM activities WHERE type = 2 AND subs_id = subs.id) AS added_points
FROM activities
JOIN subs ON activities.id = subs.id
GROUP BY subs.name
```

**NOTE:** I changed the type from VARCHAR to INT to simplify.

Comment: The specified resultset can be obtained using correlated subqueries, as shown in your example. But correlated subqueries are usually less efficient that other alternatives (for large numbers of rows). One alternative is to use expression `SUM(IF(type=1,points,0)) AS used_points` in the SELECT list. This does not use a subquery.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explaining. I didn't really think about the effiency of the alternatives as a primary factor. I'll try to check how much the efficiency is better.

Comment: For a table **activities** with 64 rows, the average time for the _correlated subqueries_ is about 5ms, while the average time with the use of the _IF expression_ is 1ms (probably less, but the engine doesn't use floating points for the time).

Comment: The difference between those is pretty negligible, not much of a performance difference. I suspect most of that difference is in the parsing and prepare of the execution plan. We'd see a bigger difference in execution time with a lots or rows returned by the outer query (distinct values for `subs.name)`. For each row returned by that outer query, each subquery in the SELECT list gets executed. And its the numerous executions of the subqueries that gets expensive (in terms of elapsed time.)

Answer (score 1):

Try change

```
IF(activities.activity_type="used_points", null, SUM(activities.points))
    AS used_points,
IF(activities.activity_type="added_points", null, SUM(activities.points))
    AS added_points
```

To next

```
SUM(IF(activities.activity_type="used_points", activities.points, 0))
    AS used_points,
SUM(IF(activities.activity_type="added_points", activities.points, 0))
    AS added_points
```

In this way you check column and sum points or 0

Comment: @BenC. This question is about MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: So it is. I'll delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

To sum a column of integer values(c1) based on another column of character values(c2). And if you need to sum only not null values, the below code will help.

```
SELECT SUM(c1) FROM table_name WHERE c2 <> '' AND c2 IS NOT NULL
```